# Where are di.xml files merged?

Tags: magento2, di

My questions is pretty simple and straight forward.

Somewhere in the code di.xml files are read and merged.

Where is this happening?

Comment: Have you referred the documentation?  **https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html**

Comment: This is a really good question. I assumed magento configuration cache but I dont know for sure. I've never questioned it until now.